# Javascript test and assignation in one line

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain this JS LINE ? data is an object.

```
var list = data == null ? [] : (data.wine instanceof Array ? data.wine : [data.wine]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is basically this;

```
var list;

if (data == null) {
    list = [];
} else {
    if (data.wine instanceof Array) {
        list = data.wine;
    } else {
        list = [data.wine];
    }
}
```

It consists of nested [ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). A ternary operator is of the form;

```
x ? y : z
```

Which evaluates `x`, and returns `y` if it is truthy, otherwise it returns `z`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (data == null) {
    list = [] 
} else {
    if (data.wine instanceof Array) {
        list = data.wine 
     else {
        list = [data.wine];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It means:

```
If data is null
    assign an empty array to list
else 
    if data.wine is of type Array
        assign data.wine to list
    else
        create an array with data.wine as the only item and assign that array to list
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As an if-else statement:

```
if (data == null)
   list = [];             // list is an empty array now
else if (data.wine instanceof Array)
   list = data.wine;      // data.wine is an array; assign it to list
else
   list = [data.wine];    // make a new array with data.wine as element
```

Answer (score 0):

its conditional operator in javascript

Conditional Operator

JavaScript also contains a conditional operator that assigns a value to a variable based on some condition.
Syntax

```
 variablename=(condition)?value1:value2 

    var variablename;
    if(condition true){
    variablename=value1;
    }
    else{
     variablename=value1;
    }
```

evaluation of your code is as follow:

```
var list;

if (data == null) {
    list = [];
} else {
    if (data.wine instanceof Array) {
        list = data.wine;
    } else {
        list = [data.wine];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you All. was confused because of the the second if else